# Getting UndefVarError: @property not defined while trying to calculate RMSE using Julia struct

Tags: julia

I am trying out `Julia`, and I would like to write a `struct` similar to a `Python` `class` which calculates the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) of two arrays. I wrote the following `Julia` code:

```
struct RMSE
    _array1::Array
    _array2::Array
    
    function RMSE(array1::Array, array2::Array)
        new(array1, array2)
    end
    
    # getter function for array1
    function RMSE.array1(r::RMSE)
        return r._array1
    end
    
    # setter function for array1
    function RMSE.array1(r::RMSE, value::Array)
        r._array1 = value
    end
    
    # getter function for array2
    function RMSE.array2(r::RMSE)
        return r._array2
    end
    
    # setter function for array2
    function RMSE.array2(r::RMSE, value::Array)
        r._array2 = value
    end
    
    # @property macro to for array1 and array2 with both a getter and a setter
    @property array1()
    @property array2()
    
    # Calculating the RMSE between the array1 and array2
    function RMSE.calculate(r::RMSE)
        sum_squares = sum((r.array1 - r.array2).^2)
        rmse = sqrt(sum_squares / length(r.array1))
        return rmse
    end
end

r = RMSE([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

r.array1 = [4, 5, 6]
r.array2 = [7, 8, 9]

rmse = r.calculate
println(rmse)
```

However, I get an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: @property not defined
in expression starting at /home/Julia/rmse_struct.jl:30
in expression starting at /home/Julia/rmse_struct.jl:1
```

I am using `Julia 1.7.2` and, as far as I know, @property was introduced in `Julia 0.7`, so there should be no issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Julia is not an object oriented language. There are no getters, setters nor functions inside structs. For data representation perhaps you want Matrix{Float64} and Vector{Float64} rather than `Array`

Comment: You can't get a Python code, remove some colons, add some "end"s and hope to work.  Your code is Pythonic. Julia is a lot different, I would suggest starting with the documentation.

Comment: If you want to code like Python in Julia (which has its specific style and syntax and everything) then leave Julia and continue with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Python, you do not have to use a . for function calls using Julia objects, and RMSE should be a function here, not an object. Your code adds the object as an argument but keeps the pythonic '.' for RMSE, which will not work here. In fact, the code you want is quite a bit simpler in Julia:

```
function RMSE(arr1, arr2)
    @assert length(arr1) == length(arr2)
    return sqrt(sum((arr1 .- arr2).^2) / length(arr1)) 
end

array1 = [4, 5, 6]
array2 = [7, 8, 9]

@show array1 array2 RMSE(array1, array2)
```